# Lookup column not showing all items in the column

Tags: list

I have list "A" and in list "A" I have a Title column.  It's a single line of text column.  In list B I have a lookup column that's setup to show items in the Title Column on list A.  Not sure when it broke, but now any new items created in list A (Title) does not show up in my list B lookup column as a choice.

Comment: Have you tried editing (but not changing anything) and saving the column settings?

Comment: Yes - I tried on both List A and B.  I created a new standard list with the title column only.  I then created a new column on list B and made it a lookup to the new standard list, Title column.  All of the items I added to my new Standard List show up..  Something bad happened the list that is not returning all items.   :(

Comment: Please make sure you didn't change the title column to multiline text

Comment: I guess the next thing I would try is adding a new lookup column to list B looking up the same field from list A and see if all the options are available.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will try look at/try your suggestions today.